# Add a scrollbar to a <textarea>

Tags: html, css, scroll, textarea

I would like to add a scrollbar to a textarea, so that it always appears, even when there is nothing to scroll down to. If there is nothing for it to scroll down to, I would prefer if it could be greyed out, indicating that there is nothing below.

How would I do this?

Comment: Use `overflow-y: scroll` , [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mr8xU/).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What you need is `overflow-y: scroll;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BmZb/)

```css
    textarea {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 100px;
        resize: none; /* Remove this if you want the user to resize the textarea */
    }
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try adding below `CSS`

```
textarea
{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to give your textarea a set height and then set overflow-y

```
textarea
{
resize: none;
overflow-y: scroll;
height:300px;
}
```

Comment: *give your textarea a set height* - Not necessary :) btw same answers..

Comment: @Mr.Alien so the height is not required?

Comment: @user2370460 not required

Answer (score 3):

```
textarea {
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Vertical scrollbar */
    overflow: scroll; /* Horizontal and vertical scrollbar*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

like this

**css**

```
textarea {

overflow:scroll;
height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="text"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#text
{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```