# Remove scrollbars from textarea

Tags: html, scroll, textarea, scrollbar, overflow

Following up to my previous question ([Add a scrollbar to a <textarea>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420923/add-a-scrollbar-to-a-textarea)) on how to always see the scrollbar in a `<textarea>`, I am now wondering how you would set it so that there is no scrollbar in the `<textarea>`, even when the text overflows. To scroll down with this, you would use the arrow keys or the mouse to navigate through the text.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try `<textarea style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>`?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Try the following, not sure which will work for all browsers or the browser you are working with, but it would be best to try all:

```
<textarea style="overflow:auto"></textarea>
```

Or

```
<textarea style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

...As suggested above

You can also try adding this, I never used it before, just saw it posted on a site today:

```
<textarea style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

This last option would remove the ability to resize the `textarea`. You can find more information on the CSS `resize` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Comment: textarea_element.style.overflow = "hidden";  (worked in Firefox 44.0)

Comment: This approach hides scrollbar, but if your content is big it doesn't scrolls it anymore.

Comment: Combine with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169328/growing-textarea-in-blazor

Comment: textarea {
            overflow:hidden;
}

worked for me in css

Answer (score 25):

`style="overflow: hidden"` and `style="resize: none"` were the ones that did the trick.

Comment: how exactly is this not an answer?

Answer (score 20):

Give a class for eg: `scroll` to the textarea tag. And in the css add this property -

```css
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<textarea class='scroll'></textarea>
```

It worked for without missing the scroll part

Comment: Perfect, you can scroll but scrollbars don't show up. Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: This is not cross browser compliant, e.g. it will not in Firefox.

Answer (score 10):

For MS IE 10 you'll probably find you need to do the following:

```
-ms-overflow-style: none
```

See the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This. Nothing else seems to work for IE10. Great stuff.

Answer (score 10):

Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll using CSS

To hide the scrollbar use -webkit- because it is supported by major browsers (Google Chrome, Safari or newer versions of Opera). There are many other options for the other browsers which are listed below:

```
    -webkit- (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera):
    .element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
    -moz- (Firefox):
    .element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
    -ms- (Internet Explorer +10):
    .element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll-using-css/

Comment: Doesn't work in FF

Comment: `.scrollable {overflow: hidden;} .scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}` works for chrome and FF.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions for just not displaying the scrollbar (instead of completely hiding overflow) mentioned in the other answers (see ::-webkit-scrollbar) work fine except for Firefox. Also the "-moz-" specific solutions mentioned are not working in Firefox for me.

Instead use:

```
scrollbar-width: none;
```

for Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of my scroll bar on the body of text by removing my max-height attribute of my class.

Answer (score 0):

Hide scroll bar for Mozilla.

```
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
```

Comment: This is not working for me in FireFox, the answer from @GoldyOnline seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

like some others mentioned, hiding the scrollbars without affecting scrolling I think is the intended behavior: https://blog.logrocket.com/hide-scrollbar-without-impacting-scrolling-css